# Get a friendly, colloquial string from JodaTime

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I've got a `org.joda.time.DateTime`, and I want to present it as such (if today is `12/18/2015 20:00`):

- `12/11/2015 07:45` becomes "December 10 at 7:45 AM"
- `12/18/2015 05:30` becomes "Today at 5:30 AM"
- `12/17/2015 21:40` becomes "Yesterday at 9:40 PM"
- `6/10/2014 13:00` becomes "June 10, 2014 at 1:00 PM"

Note: The original times are just how I'm presenting them, they're really `DateTime` objects.

I know that I can do this all manually with conditions and a bunch of different `DateTimeFormatter`s, but does there exist a library that's meant to do something like this? (Imaginary) bonus points if it has internationalization.

Comment: Well, not really, don't think there's a way to do that. Just meant it as an expression I guess. Edited.

Comment: I think ocpsoft/PrettyTime is not able to supply translations for "today" etc. see also this [issue](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime/issues/108). Only Android/DateUtils or [Time4A](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html#printRelativeOrDate-net.time4j.PlainDate-net.time4j.tz.TZID-net.time4j.CalendarUnit-net.time4j.format.TemporalFormatter-) can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK This isn't possible in JodaTime without writing some logic. To answer your question, a library to do what you want is Prettytime http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/ and it supports i18n.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Comment: (I also found something similar in Android's DateUtils class, but it's very annoying to configure and the flags don't always seem to do what they say they do.)